# best practice to divide uint16_t to get double

Tags: c++

I have two integer values and would like to obtain their quotient which should be a fractional number, in this example `37/2=18.5`. I usually do this:

```
uint16_t dividend=37;
uint16_t divisor=2;

auto quotient=dividend/double(divisor);
```

In python3 there are division `/` and truncation division `//` which result in respective quotients of `18.5` and `18`. As far as I know there is only `/` in C++ which on integers works like truncation division.

Is there a standard way of getting a `quotient==18.5` in C++?

Comment: Code Review requires concrete code from a project, with enough code and / or context for reviewers to understand how that code is used. Pseudocode, **stub code, hypothetical code**, obfuscated code, **and generic best practices** are outside the scope of this site. Please take a look at the [help/on-topic].

Comment: When you post again, post the actual section of code that is dividing two integers and obtaining their quotient, making it clear where the two integers come from, why they are integers, and why the quotient needs to be not truncated.

Comment: To get a `double` result, you need to convert (at least) one of the operands to `double` before doing the division (so your `auto quotient=dividend/double(divisor);` should be correct).

Comment: @Snowbody It would still break this rule: "We require that the poster know why the code is written the way it is."

Comment: Thanks for the discussion and pointing out that the way I posed my question was inappropriate. I'll write a better question next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the C cast in C++.
We have a specific cast for this in C++

```
auto quotient = dividend / static_cast<double>(divisor);
```

Alternatively you can simply multiply one value by 1.0

```
auto quotient = 1.0 * dividend / divisor;
```